# Spring Integration - Kafka Message Driven Channel - Auto Acknowledge

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

I have used the sample configuration as was listed in the spring io docs and it is working fine.

```
<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="kafkaListener"
        listener-container="container1"
        auto-startup="false"
        phase="100"
        send-timeout="5000"
        channel="nullChannel"
        message-converter="messageConverter"
        error-channel="errorChannel" />
```

However, when i was testing it with downstream application where i consume from kafka and publish it to downstream. If downstream is down, the messages were still getting consumed and was not replayed.

Or lets say after consuming from kafka topic , in case i find some exception in service activator, i want to throw some exception as well which should rollback the transaction so that kafka messages can be replayed.

In brief, if the consuming application is having some issue , then i want to roll back the transaction so that messages are not automatically acknowledged and are replayed back again and again unless it is succesfuly processed.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Apache Kafka works. There is the TX semantics similar to JMS. The offset in Kafka topic has nothing with rallback or redelivery.

I suggest you to study Apache Kafka closer from their official resource.

Spring Kafka brings nothing over the regular Apache Kafka protocol, however you can consider to use retry capabilities in the Spring Kafka to redeliver the same record locally : http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_retrying_deliveries

And yes, the ack mode must be MANUAL, do not commit offset into the Kafka automatically after consuming.